# Why can't Wireshark read packets from ping?

Tags: ping, wireshark

I have **Wireshark** started, then I `ping` an IP address.

But **Wireshark** is not picking up any packet sending to or receiving (echoing) from the destination address.

Why? Is `ping` "protected" from being sniffed?

Comment: You probably just started Wireshark on the wrong network interface.

Comment: It's not. Wireshark sniffs ICMP. You're doing something wrong, but we cannot guess if you give no details.

Comment: If you have started Wireshark on all network interfaces and this is Windows, then AFAIK you won't be able to capture any traffic (incl. pings) on loopback interface (127.0.0.1/8) due to the way Windows network stack works.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you aren't filtering the results
- ensure wireshark is capturing and displaying everything not just IP or TCP (ICMP is a different protocol
- Ensure you are looking at the correct network interface

Comment: how can we check if we are filtering anything like ipv4 or ICMP (with the display filter being cleared)?

Answer (score 1):

I've bumped into the same problem and what worked for me was
filtering the IP address using:

```
arp.dst.proto_ipv4 == {My.Dst.IP.Address}
```

instead of:

```
ip.addr == {My.Dst.IP.Address}
```

and then I could see the ARP messages even though I couldn't see the IP messages.

Comment: This worked for me as well. My interface was sending out ARP requests trying to figure out how to route to the destination but wasn't receiving a reply.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem (ICMP packets didn't displayed when `ping` was issued). Personally (using Wireshark 3.0.5 in Win 10), I had to filter the results by entering `icmp` in the filtering expression form in order to see the ICMP packets.